# Vectorizing taking longer than loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, array-broadcasting

My function that computes Lorentzian given freq, fwhm, amp. I want to vectorize it so that it does the computation for a list of freqs, fwhms and amps:

```
def lorz1(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm
    denominator = (2*np.pi) * ((freq_series[:,None] - freq)**2 + fwhm**2/4)
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    main_peak   = amp*(lor/np.linalg.norm(lor, axis=0))
    return np.sum(main_peak, axis=1)


def lorz2(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm[:,None]
    denominator = (2*np.pi) * ((freq_series - freq[:,None])**2 + fwhm[:,None]**2/4)
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    main_peak   = amp[:,None]*(lor/np.linalg.norm(lor, axis=1)[:,None])
    return np.sum(main_peak, axis=0)


def lorz3(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm
    denominator = (2*np.pi) * ((freq_series - freq)**2 + fwhm**2/4)
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    main_peak   = amp*(lor/np.linalg.norm(lor))
    return main_peak


series = np.linspace(0,100,50000)
freq   = np.random.uniform(5,50,50)
fwhm   = np.random.uniform(0.01,0.05,50)
amps   = np.random.uniform(5,500,50)
```

Timing:

```
%timeit lorz1(series, freq, fwhm, amps)
```

> 38.4 ms ± 1.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit lorz2(series, freq, fwhm, amps)
```

> 29.8 ms ± 1.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit np.sum(np.array([lorz3(series, item1, item2, item3)
                         for (item1,item2,item3) in zip(freq, fwhm, amps)]), axis=0)
```

> 24.1 ms ± 5.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Where am I going wrong with the vectorization in `lorz1` and `lorz2`? Aren't they supposed to be faster than `lorz3`?

Comment: The result for `np.sum(np.array([lorz3(...` is different from the other two. Is that by design?

Comment: My bad, the results for the first two are supposed to be the same as the third. I actually did not realize they were different. Is that where the problem is? 
Assume the third is "correct" and i want to vectorize that operation instead of passing the arguments one by one in a for loop.

Comment: @Homer512 Fixed that problem.

Comment: My working hypothesis (untested): Something like `freq_series - freq[:,None]` generates an array shaped `(50, 50000)`. That's about 19 MiB of memory. Your partially vectorized `lorz3` probably fits into your CPU cache much better than the fully vectorized `lorz2`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's just folding the outer loop (in the last `timeit` statement) into the function. The total number of operations should be the same unless I'm missing something

Comment: Actually, this is even faster and even less vectorized, so I think I'm onto something with my guess: `sum(lorz3(series, item1, item2, item3) for (item1,item2,item3) in zip(freq, fwhm, amps))`. Just a plain old `sum`, not converting into an array and summing in one large batch

Comment: @Homer512, interesting..! I'm open for any and all improvements. But just for my curiosity, is it not generally true that vectorization is faster than loop iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some further profiling using two versions:

Version 1:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np


def lorz2(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm[:,None]
    denominator = (2*np.pi) * ((freq_series - freq[:,None])**2 + fwhm[:,None]**2/4)
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    main_peak   = amp[:,None]*(lor/np.linalg.norm(lor, axis=1)[:,None])
    return np.sum(main_peak, axis=0)


series = np.linspace(0,100,50000)
freq   = np.random.uniform(5,50,50)
fwhm   = np.random.uniform(0.01,0.05,50)
amps   = np.random.uniform(5,500,50)

for _ in range(100):
    lorz2(series, freq, fwhm, amps)
```

and version 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import numpy as np


def lorz3(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm
    denominator = (2*np.pi) * ((freq_series - freq)**2 + fwhm**2/4)
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    main_peak   = amp*(lor/np.linalg.norm(lor))
    return main_peak


series = np.linspace(0,100,50000)
freq   = np.random.uniform(5,50,50)
fwhm   = np.random.uniform(0.01,0.05,50)
amps   = np.random.uniform(5,500,50)


for _ in range(100):
    sum(lorz3(series, item1, item2, item3)
        for (item1,item2,item3) in zip(freq, fwhm, amps))
```

Notice how I tweaked the summation for `lorz3` into a plain old Python `sum`. This is faster in my tests since it avoids the temporary array construction.

Here are the results of some profiling I did:

```bash
perf stat -ddd ./lorz2.py

 Performance counter stats for './lorz2.py':

           2729.16 msec task-clock:u                     #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
                 0      context-switches:u               #    0.000 /sec                      
                 0      cpu-migrations:u                 #    0.000 /sec                      
            217114      page-faults:u                    #   79.554 K/sec                     
        8192141440      cycles:u                         #    3.002 GHz                         (38.43%)
        3178961202      instructions:u                   #    0.39  insn per cycle              (46.12%)
         426575242      branches:u                       #  156.303 M/sec                       (53.81%)
           2177628      branch-misses:u                  #    0.51% of all branches             (61.51%)
       42020185035      slots:u                          #   15.397 G/sec                       (69.20%)
         323473974      topdown-retiring:u               #      0.6% Retiring                   (69.20%)
       33616148028      topdown-bad-spec:u               #     67.1% Bad Speculation            (69.20%)
         371211166      topdown-fe-bound:u               #      0.7% Frontend Bound             (69.20%)
       15767347418      topdown-be-bound:u               #     31.5% Backend Bound              (69.20%)
         813550722      L1-dcache-loads:u                #  298.096 M/sec                       (69.19%)
         546814255      L1-dcache-load-misses:u          #   67.21% of all L1-dcache accesses   (69.21%)
          82889242      LLC-loads:u                      #   30.372 M/sec                       (69.22%)
          67633317      LLC-load-misses:u                #   81.59% of all LL-cache accesses    (69.24%)
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads:u                                                     
           9705348      L1-icache-load-misses:u          #    0.00% of all L1-icache accesses   (30.81%)
         864895659      dTLB-loads:u                     #  316.909 M/sec                       (30.79%)
            117310      dTLB-load-misses:u               #    0.01% of all dTLB cache accesses  (30.78%)
   <not supported>      iTLB-loads:u                                                          
             85530      iTLB-load-misses:u               #    0.00% of all iTLB cache accesses  (30.76%)
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetches:u                                                
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u                                           

       2.729696014 seconds time elapsed

       1.932708000 seconds user
       0.796504000 seconds sys
```

And here the faster version:

```bash
 Performance counter stats for './lorz3.py':

            878.49 msec task-clock:u                     #    0.999 CPUs utilized             
                 0      context-switches:u               #    0.000 /sec                      
                 0      cpu-migrations:u                 #    0.000 /sec                      
             52869      page-faults:u                    #   60.182 K/sec                     
        3704170220      cycles:u                         #    4.217 GHz                         (38.22%)
        3735225800      instructions:u                   #    1.01  insn per cycle              (45.96%)
         568575253      branches:u                       #  647.221 M/sec                       (53.70%)
           2580294      branch-misses:u                  #    0.45% of all branches             (61.43%)
       18355798588      slots:u                          #   20.895 G/sec                       (69.17%)
        3328525030      topdown-retiring:u               #     17.5% Retiring                   (69.17%)
        6982401815      topdown-bad-spec:u               #     36.6% Bad Speculation            (69.17%)
        1297505291      topdown-fe-bound:u               #      6.8% Frontend Bound             (69.17%)
        7459691283      topdown-be-bound:u               #     39.1% Backend Bound              (69.17%)
         858082535      L1-dcache-loads:u                #  976.773 M/sec                       (69.28%)
         430569310      L1-dcache-load-misses:u          #   50.18% of all L1-dcache accesses   (69.40%)
          15723297      LLC-loads:u                      #   17.898 M/sec                       (69.49%)
             73709      LLC-load-misses:u                #    0.47% of all LL-cache accesses    (69.50%)
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads:u                                                     
          38705486      L1-icache-load-misses:u          #    0.00% of all L1-icache accesses   (30.72%)
         860276161      dTLB-loads:u                     #  979.270 M/sec                       (30.60%)
             86213      dTLB-load-misses:u               #    0.01% of all dTLB cache accesses  (30.51%)
   <not supported>      iTLB-loads:u                                                          
             91069      iTLB-load-misses:u               #    0.00% of all iTLB cache accesses  (30.50%)
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetches:u                                                
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u                                           

       0.878946776 seconds time elapsed

       0.852205000 seconds user
       0.026744000 seconds sys
```

Notice how the number of instructions is actually slightly higher in the faster code, which makes sense since it is less vectorized, but the much higher instructions per cycle make it faster overall. There are twice as many LLC loads in the slower version, of which most miss while here almost all hit. I'm not sure how to interpret the `topdown-bad-spec` counter. Maybe someone else can comment on that.

The CPU even clocks down (this is reproducible) which supports the idea that it is simply waiting on memory.

Further, notice the `sys` time in the last line. `lorz2` spends 28% of its runtime in kernel space. Since it doesn't do anything IO-related, that is all memory allocation and deallocation overhead.

We can look a bit further at the stall reasons:

```bash
perf stat -e cycles,l1d_pend_miss.l2_stall,cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss ./lorz2.py

 Performance counter stats for './lorz2.py':

        8446540078      cycles:u                                                              
        1953955881      l1d_pend_miss.l2_stall:u                                              
        3050292324      cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss:u                                       

       2.748141433 seconds time elapsed

       1.959570000 seconds user
       0.788443000 seconds sys
```

```bash
perf stat -e cycles,l1d_pend_miss.l2_stall,cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss ./lorz3.py

 Performance counter stats for './lorz3.py':

        3674547216      cycles:u                                                              
         303870088      l1d_pend_miss.l2_stall:u                                              
          16939496      cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss:u                                       

       0.869909182 seconds time elapsed

       0.848122000 seconds user
       0.021752000 seconds sys
```

So, the `lorz2` version just stalls constantly on level 2 or 3 cache misses.

We can further look at a simple `perf report`

```bash
perf record ./lorz2.py
perf report


# Overhead  Command  Shared Object                                      Symbol                                         
# ........  .......  .................................................  ...............................................
#
    32.44%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_multiply
    27.03%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_divide
    17.34%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_add
     6.93%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_subtract
     6.12%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_pairwise_sum
     5.32%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_square
     0.51%  python3  [unknown]                                          [k] 0xffffffffb2800fe7
     0.46%  python3  libpython3.11.so.1.0                               [.] _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
     0.19%  python3  libpython3.11.so.1.0                               [.] unicodekeys_lookup_unicode
     0.18%  python3  libpython3.11.so.1.0                               [.] gc_collect_main
...
```

```bash
perf record ./lorz3.py
perf report

# Overhead  Command  Shared Object                                      Symbol                                       
# ........  .......  .................................................  .............................................
#
    27.56%  python3  libblas.so.3.11.0                                  [.] ddot_
    27.47%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_divide
     8.64%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_subtract
     8.34%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_add
     5.84%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_multiply
     3.70%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] DOUBLE_square
     1.47%  python3  libpython3.11.so.1.0                               [.] _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
     1.38%  python3  libgcc_s.so.1                                      [.] execute_cfa_program
     0.89%  python3  libgcc_s.so.1                                      [.] uw_update_context_1
     0.88%  python3  libgcc_s.so.1                                      [.] _Unwind_Find_FDE
     0.64%  python3  libgcc_s.so.1                                      [.] uw_frame_state_for
     0.61%  python3  _multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] ufunc_generic_fastcall
...
```

Huh, that's interesting. Where does the dot product come from? I assume this is how `linalg.norm` is implemented for simple vectors.

Incidentally, we can speed up the `lorz2` and `lorz3` versions slightly via 3 measures:

1. Fold multiplication and summation into one matrix multiplication
2. Reorder some operations to execute them on smaller arrays (or scalars)
3. Replace divisions with multiplications by the inverse

```py
def lorz2a(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm[:,None] * (0.5 / np.pi)
    denominator = (freq_series - freq[:,None])**2 + 0.25 * fwhm[:,None]**2
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    return (amp / np.linalg.norm(lor, axis=1)) @ lor

    
def lorz3a(freq_series, freq, fwhm, amp):
    numerator   = fwhm * (0.5 / np.pi)
    denominator = (freq_series - freq)**2 + 0.25 * fwhm**2
    lor         = numerator / denominator
    main_peak   = amp / np.linalg.norm(lor) * lor
    return main_peak
```

This does not change anything on the overall trends, however.

### In conclusion

Numpy vectorization primarily helps reducing per-call overhead. Once the arrays are large enough, we don't get much benefit from it since the remaining interpreter overhead is small compared to the computations itself. Simultaneously, larger arrays result in reduced memory efficiency. Typically there is a sweet-spot somewhere around L2 or L3 cache size. The `lorz3` implementation hits this spot better than the others.

For a smaller series size and a larger size of the other arrays, we can expect `lorz2` to perform better. For example this data set makes my `lorz2a` faster than my `lorz3a`:

```py
series = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
freq   = np.random.uniform(5,50,2000)
fwhm   = np.random.uniform(0.01,0.05,2000)
amps   = np.random.uniform(5,500,2000)
```

Numpy's simple, eager evaluation scheme puts the onus of tuning for this on the user. Other libraries like [NumExpr](https://pypi.org/project/numexpr/) try to avoid this.

Comment: yes, I've often noted that  a few iterations (e.g.5) on a complex task can be faster than the equivalent 'whole array' code.  I attribute it to the increased complexity of handling larger arrays, though others can explain it better in terms of memory layout, paging and caching.

Comment: What a detailed answer! I highly appreciate it. Learnt quite a few things today. Thank you.